# How to find the centre of mass of an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry

I have a pentagon lamina with all the sides length 8 cm to find the centre of mass of the pentagon. Do you do:

$$\frac{4+8+ \frac{1}{3}\times\text{something}}{8^2+16\sqrt3}\ ?$$

A uniform lamina *ABCDE* consists of a square *ACDE* and an equilateral triangle *ABC.* Find the distance of the centre of mass from *AC.*

Comment: Pentagon or equilateral triangle? Also, a center of mass is going to be a *point*, not a number.

Comment: the 'something' indicates the part to do with finding centre of mass of the triangle. And yes my working is trying to find the y value of the pentagon.

Comment: The three perpendicular bisectors of an equilateral triangle intersect at a single point, which is its centroid.  I presume you are wanting to break up the regular pentagon into five composite equilateral triangles; this geometric fact will give you a measurement to work with.

Comment: Ohh-kay, so now it's _not_ a regular pentagon...

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the sides is not enough. You probably mean that also the *angles* are all equal, so we are dealing with the **regular pentagon** of side $8$.

The centre of mass will be at the centre of the circle that the regular pentagon is inscribed in.

To describe the *location* of the centre, imagine that $AB$ is one of the edges, and let $O$ be the centre of the circle. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. To get to $O$, we draw the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, and go up a distance $d$ from $M$, where $d=4\tan(54^\circ)$.

**Remark:** One can get an explicit expression for the required $\tan(54^\circ)$ in terms of square roots if that is desired.  It turns out that
$$\tan(54^\circ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}}.$$

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have an irregular pentagon with all sides equal, right?

Comment: Here is an extreme case. Draw a line of length $2$, with a point in thw middle. That's the bottom, two of the sides. For two other sides, go up at $60^\circ$, for length $1$, and join up. There are plenty of less ectreme cases. You may be thinking of the true fact that for odd $n$, if all **angles** are equal, then all sides are.

Answer (score 2):

Ler $A$ be the center of mass of the triangle, $B$ of the square, $C$ of the lamina. Then (we are calculating a barycentre), $$C = \frac{\text{Area(triangle)}A + \text{Area(square)}B}{\text{Area(lamina)}}$$.

$$B = (4,4)$$ $$C = (4, 8+4 \tan(\pi/6)) = (4, 8 + 4/\sqrt{3})$$
$$Area(square) = 64$$
$$\text{Area(triangle)} = 8 \times 4\tan(\pi/3) = 16\sqrt{3}$$

If we put $C=(x,y)$, $x=4$ and $$y = \frac{64\times4 + 16\sqrt{3} \times (8 + 4/\sqrt{3})}{16\sqrt{3} + 64}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a general *n*-gon that is being split into *n* triangles each containing one edge and the origin.

[image: fig1]

You want to find the area and center of mass for the *n*-gon, and you do that by summing up the area of each triangle, and calculating the center of mass contribution of each triangle. Note that some triangles will have *negative* area and when they are all added up only the area enclosed inside the *n*-gon will remain.

Specifically

$$ \begin{aligned}{\rm area}_{i} & =\tfrac{1}{2}\left(x_{i}y_{i+1}-y_{i}x_{i+1}\right)\\
{\rm area}_{{\rm tot}} & =\sum_{i}^{n}{\rm area}_{i}\\
\underline{{\rm cm}}_{{\rm tot}} & =\tfrac{1}{{\rm area}_{{\rm tot}}}\sum_{i}^{n}{\rm area}_{i}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{x_{i}+x_{i+1}}{3}\\
\frac{y_{i}+y_{i+1}}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned} $$